# Sort JavaScript Array having the array of Object

Tags: javascript, sorting, time-complexity

Can you please suggest me the best way to sort the below array by the priority based on the name of the section. I am more worried on the time complexity as my array in real consist of 100 000 records.

I am okay also to change the array structure if there any better way to store

```
[{
    id: 'field1',
    sections: [{
        name: 'Top_Section',
        priority: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Bottom_Section',
        priority: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'field2',
    sections: [{
        name: 'Top_Section',
        priority: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Bottom_Section',
        priority: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'field3',
    sections: [{
        name: 'Top_Section',
        priority: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Bottom_Section',
        priority: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'field4',
    sections: [{
        name: 'Top_Section',
        priority: 4
      },
      {
        name: 'Bottom_Section',
        priority: 2
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Like I wanted to sort priority based on the Top_Section so my expected output should be as below
as the field3 is having priority 1 and field2 is having priority 2 etc.

```
[
  {
    id: 'field3',
    sections: [
      { name: 'Top_Section', priority: 1 },
      { name: 'Bottom_Section', priority: 1 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'field2',
    sections: [
      { name: 'Top_Section', priority: 2 },
      { name: 'Bottom_Section', priority: 4 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'field1',
    sections: [
      { name: 'Top_Section', priority: 3 },
      { name: 'Bottom_Section', priority: 3 }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'field4',
    sections: [
      { name: 'Top_Section', priority: 4 },
      { name: 'Bottom_Section', priority: 2 }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.sort()` and then test it. 100.000 entries shouldn't take that long.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that 'Top_Section' is always on the first position in the sections array.

I'm also assuming that there will be only two types of priority types: 'Top_Section' and 'Bottom_Section'

```js
let list = [{
    id: 'field1',
    sections: [{
        name: 'Top_Section',
        priority: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'Bottom_Section',
        priority: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'field2',
    sections: [{
        name: 'Top_Section',
        priority: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'Bottom_Section',
        priority: 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'field3',
    sections: [{
        name: 'Top_Section',
        priority: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Bottom_Section',
        priority: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'field4',
    sections: [{
        name: 'Top_Section',
        priority: 4
      },
      {
        name: 'Bottom_Section',
        priority: 2
      }
    ]
  }
];

function sortBy(priorityName) {
  let priorityPosition = (priorityName == 'Top_Section') ? 0 : 1;
  
  return (a, b) => {
    return a['sections'][priorityPosition].priority - b['sections'][priorityPosition].priority;
  }
}

console.log( list.sort(sortBy('Top_Section')) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's create a comparator

```
function compare(a, b) {
    var sumA = 0;
    var sumB = 0;
    for (var section of a.sections) sumA += section.priority;
    for (var section of b.sections) sumB += seciton.priority;
    return sumB - sumA;
}

arr.sort(compare);
```

The comparator returns positive if the first parameter is greater, negative if the second parameter is greater and 0 if they are equal. I assumed that the lowest the numeric value of the sum of the priorities, the greater the item is.

Comment: @Ron great. Please let me know about your results.